# Stacked Bar Chart in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, stacked-chart

I am very new to VBA and have little coding experience, so any help is greatly appreciated.

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart in VBA. Essentially, I have discovery dates in my C column in the format of M/DD/YYYY, and I have error types in my H column (i.e. human, manufacturing, etc). I need to create a stacked bar chart with month on the x axis and number of errors on the y axis. The bars with then be broken down into colors based on how many errors of each type.

I am very lost on how to achieve this in VBA. My general idea was to do a counter of some sort in a for loop. I am unsure of syntax and just how to achieve this chart in general. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much.

Edit:
Here is the code I have so far. Trying to count the instances of specific errors but I don't know how I would be able to count the instances of certain errors per month.

```
Sub Interim_Tracker()

    'Declares discovery date as range
    Dim DiscoveryDate As Range
    Dim RootCause As Range
    
    'Declares errors as singles
    Dim HumanError As Single
    Dim EquipmentError As Single
    Dim MaterialError As Single
    Dim Method_ProcedureError As Single
    Dim EnvironmentError As Single
    Dim UnknownError As Single
    
    'Declares criteria as strings
    Dim CriteriaValueHumanError As String
    Dim CriteriaValueEquipmentError As String
    Dim CriteriaValueMaterialError As String
    Dim CriteriaValueMethod_ProcedureError As String
    Dim CriteriaValueEnvironmentError As String
    Dim CriteriaValueUnknownError As String
    
    'Sets discovery date range to appropriate column
    Set DiscoveryDate = Worksheets("Macros Test Sheet").Range("C2:C1000")
    Set RootCause = Worksheets("Macros Test Sheet").Range("H2:H1000")
    
    
    'Sets criteria values
    CriteriaValueHumanError = "Human"
    CriteriaValueEquipmentError = "Equipment"
    CriteriaValueMaterialError = "Material"
    CriteriaValueMethod_ProcedureError = "Method/Procedure"
    CriteriaValueEnvironmentError = "Environment"
    CriteriaValueUnknownError = "Unknown"
    
    'Counts occurences of errors in column
    HumanError = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RootCause, CriteriaValueHumanError)
    EquipmentError = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RootCause, CriteriaValueEquipmentError)
    MaterialError = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RootCause, CriteriaValueMaterialError)
    Method_ProcedureError = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RootCause, CriteriaValueMethod_ProcedureError)
    EnvironementError = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RootCause, CriteriaValueEnvironmentError)
    UnknownError = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(RootCause, CriteriaValueUnknownError)
    
    
End Sub
```

I know this is no where near complete, but when I do run it, I get the subscript out of range error when I set the ranges to be either the C or H column.

Here is the chart I am trying to produce this output:

[image: DesiredOutput]

Comment: Care to share some code, just enough to illustrate the problem at hand? Also a picture of the type of chart would be nice, since Excel has a built in ability to do stacked bar chart, how would this be different from what you want.

Comment: @JAlex Yes! I have edited my post. Your help is greatly appreciated. Basically I am trying to create a macro and then assign this macro to a button so that when it is clicked, it will create this stacked bar chart.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to place all the data on hidden sheet/scratch page to form a table with categories in the first column, and series names on the first now.

Then call code as follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

    Dim n As Long, m As Long
    ' n = num of categories
    ' m = num of series
    n = 4
    m = 3

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ws.Range("A3")
    Set r = r.Resize(n + 1, m + 1)
    
    Dim s As Shape
    Set s = ws.Shapes.AddChart2(-1, xlColumnStacked)
    s.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=r
End Sub
```

This is an example on how the data should be laid out starting from `A3`

[image: scr1]

Comment: Note that recording a macro results in `.AddChart2(297, xlColumnStacked)` instead, and I am not sure what the `297` code indicates. I have included `-1` which means _use default style_ in my answer.